# Category of elements as a coend, and the right adjoint of $X//G$

Tags: ct.category-theory

How is the weight $J(-)$ determined in this characterization of the category of element of a copresheaf as a coend?
http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/category+of+elements#properties_11

The functor el(-) seems to admit a right adjoint given by $D \to K(D)$ : $c\mapsto Ob([Jc, D])$, which would imply cocontinuity; am I right in deducing this from a purely formal-nonsense argument?

I'm trying to unravel the coend definition in the simple example of the action groupoid of a G-set, to see if I'm able to find what $J$ has to be at least in that case. Maybe this is linked to the presence of an adjoint for the functor $X\mapsto X//G$ from G-sets to groupoids. Does anybody know a reference for that?

Thanks.

Comment: @tetrapharmakon, the category of elements is obtained by a special case of the Grothendieck construction. In light of this comment, the first part of your question has been answered in: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/128393/grothendieck-construction-for-profunctors
If you take a careful glimpse into mentioned Ross Street's paper, you'll find the answer to your second question as well.

Comment: I hoped for a more explicit answer (for example clarifying how is $J$ obtained starting from the functor $F$), but in any case, thank you...

Comment: Actually, in the literature, there are two concepts of categories of elements --- one for covariant functors $F \colon \mathbb{C} \rightarrow \mathbf{Set}$, and the other for contravariant functors  $G \colon \mathbb{C}^{op} \rightarrow \mathbf{Set}$. These categories are defined as follows:
$$\begin{array}{lcl}
\mathit{elt}(F) &=& \int^{C \in \mathbb{C}} C/\mathbb{C} \times F(C)\newline
\mathit{elt}^{op}(G) &=& \int^{C \in \mathbb{C}} \mathbb{C}/C \times G(C)\newline
\end{array}$$

Comment: where the functor:
$$\mathbb{C}/(-) \colon \mathbb{C} \rightarrow \mathbf{Cat}$$
is defined on arrows by:
$$\mathbb{C}/(C \overset{f}\rightarrow D) \mapsto \lambda [X \overset{h}\rightarrow C]. f \circ h$$
and similarly the functor:
$$(-)/\mathbb{C} \colon \mathbb{C}^{op} \rightarrow \mathbf{Cat}$$
is defined by:
$$(D \overset{g}\rightarrow C)/\mathbb{C} \mapsto \lambda [C \overset{k}\rightarrow X]. k \circ g$$



Comment: Definitely more clear! :)

So if I understood you are weighting with the functor $\mathbf C\to \bf Cat$ which sends $c$ either to the category of arrows above or below $c\in \bf C$? Is there a hands-on way to show that elt(F) really is the cat of elements (e.g. appealing to the definition or the characterization as comma category)? At this point, I'm planning to add a couple of row in the nlab entry.

Comment: Doesn't it follow from Yoneda lemma? BTW, I don't understand your sequence of characters defining a right adjoint to the Gothendieck construction. Anyway, it is easy to show $\mathit{elt}(-) \dashv (=)^{(-)/\mathbb{C}}$  by simple coend-computation:
$$\begin{array}{c}
\hom(\int^{C \in \mathbb{C}} C/\mathbb{C} \times F(C), \mathbb{D})\newline\hline\newline\hline
\int_{C \in \mathbb{C}}\hom( C/\mathbb{C} \times F(C), \mathbb{D})\newline\hline\newline\hline
\int_{C \in \mathbb{C}}\hom(F(C), \mathbb{D}^{C/\mathbb{C}})\newline\hline\newline\hline
\mathit{nat}(F(-), X^{(-)/\mathbb{C}})
\end{array}$$

Comment: You have to take care of the embedding $\delta\colon \bf Sets\to Cat$ regarding sets as discrete cats. Once you do this, you'll notice that
$$\begin{array}{c}
\left[  \int^C JC\times\delta(FC), \mathbf D\right]\\ \int_C\big[JC\times \delta(FC),\mathbf D\big]\\ \int_C \mathbf Sets\big(FC,[JC,\mathbf D]\big)\\ 
\mathrm{Nat}(F, K(\mathbf D))
\end{array}$$
where $K(\mathbf D)\colon C\mapsto Ob([JC,\mathbf D])$.

Comment: > Doesn't it follow from Yoneda lemma?
Indeed it may be (as 90% of categorical facts). :) but how? 

Thanks for your invaluable help!